# How to auto convert camel case request body to snake case protobuf message in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, protobuf-java

I have a endpoint like this

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create")
    public Mono<?> issueToken(@RequestBody IssuePayTokenRequest request) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> tokenManagementService.issuePayToken(request)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }
```

And the IssuePayTokenRequest is a protobuf message, like this

```
message IssuePayTokenRequest {
  string client_id = 1;
}
```

According to Google protobuf's style guide, I should use snake case style for fields, so when client call this endpoint, the request body should like this.

```
{ "client_id": "abcdefg"}
```

However, for JSON style guide, the field should use camel case, like this

```
{ "clientId": "abcdefg"}
```

Can I do some configuration to let Spring Boot auto convert a camel case style request body to a snake case style protobuf message?

PS: It's legacy project and I'm not familiar with Spring, but I found this code in the Configuartion class.

```
@Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                .featuresToDisable(
                        JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN,
                        MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION,
                        DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,
                        SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS
                )
                .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
                .propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)
                .modulesToInstall(ProtobufModule.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = objectMapper();
        configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper));
        configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper));
    }
```

Seems it should convert camel case json to snake case protobuf automaticly. But it doesn't work as I wish.

Answer (score 3):

Try put this configuration on your DTO:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
```

Or, you can do a custom configuration to objectMapper bean to affect all objects:

```
@Bean
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
 return new ObjectMapper()
  .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieved by adding the following property

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```